# Induction involving binomial coefficients ${n \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, induction, binomial-coefficients

Why, many times, in problems involving binomial coefficients, ${n \choose k}$, that we need induction to prove something, we use induction on $k$ instead on $n$. Since $n$ limits $k$, it seems strange to me to prove it for all $k$, since once proven, $k$ would "extrapolate" $n$, as it goes to infinity. You can say that $n$ also goes to infinity, but it sounds strange to me because when would $k$ then reach $n$?

Comment: Do you have a specific example that you're confused by, and an explanation of what it is about it confuses you?

Comment: If you have some statement $A(n,k)$ and you prove it for all $k$, this is not the same as proving it for all $n$.  You have some specific $n$, and you've shown $A(n,0), A(n, 1), \ldots$ are all true.  If you lay out $A(n,k)$ in a table format, you've shown a particular row of statements are true, but you haven't shown it for all rows. I'm not sure if that answers your question or not.